# is there a way to declare local methods in class, ruby?

Tags: ruby

I can declare instance method

```
def method_name ...
```

I can declare class method

```
def self.method_name ...
```

But how do i declare internal private local methods in class or is not possible? So that they can't be accessed by like this `Class.method_name` or `Class.new.method_name`

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if you find any of them helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use private keyword, 
something like this:

```
private
   def mehtod_name ...
```

and other way is:

```
private_class_method :method_name, :other_method_name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can declare private instance methods add the `private` keyword. Every method below that will be private:

```
class Foo
  private
  def bar
    #...
  end
end
```

To create private class methods you need the `private_class_method` method:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    #...
  end
  private_class_method :bar
end
```

Comment: ...and if you've already defined `bar` as public (or protected), you can use the method [Module#private](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-private) to make it private: `private(:bar)` or `private("bar")`.

Comment: Also, since Ruby 2.0 `def` returns the method name as a `Symbol`, so you can do `private def bar; end` and `private_class_method def self.bar; end` as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Test

  private_class_method :greet
  def self.greet
    print "Hello"
  end

end

Test.greet  # Error
```